# MockReturnValue is returning undefined on axios wrapper function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jestjs, wrapper

I am trying to test my componentDidMount and ensure that this axiosRequest returns an array. However no matter how I mock my axiosRequest function, it always returns undefined. What am I missing??

My axiosRequest wrapper fn:

```
export const axiosRequest = (type, url, body, headers) => {
  return axios[type](url,
  {
    ...body,
    sharedLinkToken: store.getState()?.token ? store.getState()?.token : null,
    activeWorkspace: body?.activeWorkspace ? body?.activeWorkspace : 
      store.getState()?.auth?.org?.activeWorkspace,
  },
  { ...headers },
 ).then((res) => res?.data);
};
```

Calling said function in my CDM

```
async componentDidMount() {
  try {
    const fieldTypes = await axiosRequest('post', '/api/custom-fields/types');
    console.log('fieldTypes: ', fieldTypes);
    this.setState({ fieldTypes });
  } catch (e) {
    this.setState({ disable: true });
  }
}
```

My test with its imports with my various ways to mock this function:

```
import * as axiosRequest from '../../../../utilities/utilities';
let mockAxiosRequest;
// jest.mock('axios');
// jest.mock('../../../../utilities/utilities', () => ({
//   axiosRequest: jest.fn(),
// }));
beforeEach(() => {
  props = {};
  wrapper = shallow(<CreateCustomField {...props} />);
  instance = wrapper.instance();
  mockAxiosRequest = jest.spyOn(axiosRequest, 'axiosRequest');
});

it('Should find the wrapper', async () => {
  mockAxiosRequest.mockResolvedValue(['stuff']);
  // mockAxiosRequest.mockResolvedValue(() => ['stuff']);
  // mockAxiosRequest.mockResolvedValueOnce(['stuff']);
  // mockAxiosRequest.mockReturnThis(['stuff']);
  // mockAxiosRequest.mockImplementation(() => ['stuff']);
  // mockAxiosRequest.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(['stuff']));
  expect(wrapper.find('.create-custom-fields-modal').length).toBe(1);
  expect(instance.state.fieldTypes.length).toBe(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that my mocks were working fine, however the componentDidMount was the issue. So because of this, I am doing everything manually, and everything is working as expected.

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {};
    mockAxiosRequest = jest.spyOn(axiosRequest, 'axiosRequest');
    wrapper = shallow(<CreateCustomField {...props} />, { disableLifecycleMethods: true });
    instance = wrapper.instance();
    instance.setState({ fieldTypeOptions: [{ persistent_id: '123',field_type: 'Date & Time' }] });
  });
```

Then my two tests that are now passing:

```
  it('Should find the wrapper', async () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('.create-custom-fields-modal').length).toBe(1);
  });
  it('Should call componentDidMount', async () => {
    mockAxiosRequest.mockResolvedValueOnce([
     { persistent_id: '456', field_type: 'Date & Time' },
     { persistent_id: '123', field_type: 'Number' },
    ]);
    await instance.componentDidMount();
    expect(instance.state.fieldTypeOptions.length).toBe(2);
  });
```